# How to use an external php file to view images in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

So I am taking a web project from a web server and using it in XAMPP. In the original code, A user selects a file to upload. On submit the file is moved to the upload folder outside of the public html folder, and then the database is updated with the file name. I then use a select statement to get the file name from the database. Then I use a php include file to view the image within the img tag with the file name from the database.

I made an upload folder in the project folder to store images(as if it were the upload folder in a web server), and changed the file paths respectively.

So my problem is that the image does not show, everything else works up until I get to the image file that reads the image and I don't know why. I've tried to echo out the $image variable to see the path and it does not show either. So I think its the image file itself but can't be sure. Not sure where to go from here.

Please read this carefully.

File Structure:

**projectfolder**

-includes

-pagelets

-upload

pagelet code:

```
<?php
//Upload Image
if (isset($_POST['uploadImg'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "upload/{$_FILES['image']['name']}")) {
            echo "File Uploaded";
        }else{
            echo "File not uploaded";
            $i = '';
        }
        $i = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    }else{
        $i ='';
    }

    //Update database
    $query = "UPDATE Employees SET Photo = '$i' WHERE EmployeeID = {$_SESSION['EmpId']}";
    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);//Run the query
}
$query = "SELECT EmployeeID AS id, Photo AS photo, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS name, PhoneNumber AS phone, Email AS email FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = '{$_SESSION['EmpId']}'";
$infoResult = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);//Run the query
if($infoResult){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($infoResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
?>
<div id="profile-pic">
        <?php
            echo "<img src=\"includes/view-image.inc.php?file={$row['photo']}\" alt=\"{$row['photo']}\" />";
        ?>
        <form name="uploadForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>?pagelet=Dashboard" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image">

            <input type="submit" name="uploadImg" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Include file:

```
<?php
$path = "/upload/"; //directory outside public_html on the server
$file = ($_GET['file']);
$image = $path.$file;
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
@readfile($image);
?>
```

Comment: what is the current file path?

Comment: that is **EXTREMELY** 
dangerous code. you're allowing access to ANY file on your server for which they know the path. e.g. `example.com/include.php?file=../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: No the php code cannot be viewed in a browser. They could change the file name to a different path but it would not be read. Plus I'm trying to figure this out so that I can do some validation such as file extension, size, etc...

Answer (score 2):

While you are uploading the file, you might be able to work with any folder on any place if they are writable. Because the uploading process is server side. But, when you want to access the file to show it on web, you should use a path which is inside public_html.

So, move the upload folder inside the public_html folder and recorrect the path of your uploading process. Then, your code works well.

For example, the directory should be something like this:

> public_html/
>
> -- upload/

Comment: The code works on a web server, it doesn't in XAMPP. I need a suggestion that allows me to use this code in XAMPP. The upload folder IS in the project folder(public_html)

Comment: @JavaFox, so, for sure your path configuration missed something. Could you confirm if the upload is out of public_html on server too?

Comment: The upload folder is outside of the public_html folder as in all web servers I would think. However I am trying to do this in XAMPP. So I made an upload folder within the project folder and used that path, which I would think should work. The point is to simulate  the same file structure as a web server. SO, in XAMPP, within the htdocs folder, is my project folder where everything lies, as well as the upload folder. The upload folder in in the project folder.

Comment: @JavaFox, Usually, if you ar going to give access a file to a web client, that file should be in the document root. Otherwise, it's too dangerous.

Comment: Correct, and I would do that and make those changes when uploading the site to a web server. But what about taking a site from a web server to your local machine and use it in XAMPP? How would I make this code work in XAMPP?

Comment: @JavaFox, it's not easy to say a general solution. Usually, you can copy the files and directory from server to your local. Then, find all the configuration files and recorrect them by your path, credentials, ... .

Comment: But shouldn't the code still work If everything is within the project folder? What you just said is in fact the question. Usually doing what you said works. I did this and it doesn't XD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120252/discussion-between-mojtaba-and-javafox).